# When I try to call the Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe method in inline mode, the Telegram web app API returns an empty object - python & tg webapp

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I'm attempting to retrieve user data, but the method is returning an empty object.
bot.py

```
menuId = "id"
webapp = "https://localhost" + "/" + menuId

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

def webAppKeyboardInline(): 
   keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1) 
   webApp = types.WebAppInfo(webapp) 
   one = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Open", web_app=webApp) 
   keyboard.add(one) 

   return keyboard

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "hello!", reply_markup=webAppKeyboardInline())


bot.infinity_polling()
```

There is nothing interesting on the website, I simply get an object. But, despite the button type, it is always an empty object.

I've experimented with various button techniques.

Comment: menuId = "id", shouldn't it be actual id?